# Can I use MacBook Pro's 61W power adapter to charge my iPhone 12

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ios, battery, power

I have bought a new iPhone 12 64GB. But because now Apple has removed the charging adapter from the box, I need to buy a new one. I have a MacBook pro-2019, I want to know if I can use my MacBook's 61W power adapter to charge my iPhone. I just want to be sure that it won't damage my iPhone's battery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I charge an iPhone with another device's USB charger?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/can-i-charge-an-iphone-with-another-devices-usb-charger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Your iPhone will draw the appropriate amount of power from the MacBook USB-C charger.

For more information, such as which iPhone models and which Apple chargers can be used, refer to [Fast charge your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/HT208137) on Apple's website.